# Reordering, solving for denominator (simple task)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Very simple question, but I just need to check if my head is working correct, been a while since I did math and reordering.

This is my intuitive solution, so I'm wondering if this is the correct way, many of the steps are included to illustrate my thinking.

Actual equation, want to solve for n:
$$MOE = Z \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Showing my thinking:
$$\frac{MOE}{1} =  \frac{Z}{1}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Moving $\sqrt{n}$ to the other side, therefor changing order of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ to $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1}$
$$\sqrt{n} = \frac{Z \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{1 \cdot MOE \cdot 2}$$

Edit after comments, to check if my thinking is now more correct:
$$ \frac{1}{MOE}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n}}{1}\cdot\frac{MOE}{1} =  \frac{Z}{1}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{MOE}$$

Solving all the 1's:
$$ \sqrt{n} = \frac{Z}{2 \cdot MOE} $$

$^2$ both sides to remove $\sqrt{}$ from n
$$ n = \left( \frac{Z}{2 \cdot MOE} \right)^2$$

Is this the correct way of thinking/solving this? I know the answer is correct, but is the path to the answer correct?

Comment: Other than "moving $\sqrt n$ to the other side"  being more accurately  thought  of as "multiplying both sides by $\sqrt n$" (and dividing both sides by MOE), it  is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, although I don't see the point of all the 1s. You are just multiplying both sides by $\sqrt{n}$ and dividing both sides by $2\cdot MOE$, and finally squaring both sides.

Comment: Yeah it seems fine. But remember that squaring both sides may introduce new solutions, for example if x=1 so $x^2$=1 we have introduced the solution x=-1.

Comment: @Extended ?? The OP is trying to get $n$. Squaring has no effect on the number of solutions.

Comment: Yeah in this case it doesn't matter, but I was saying that in general squaring may introduce new solutions.